# Segmentation fault while using std::map<std::string, GLuint>!

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, segmentation-fault, c++11

I have a Segmentation fault while using `std::map<std::string, GLuint>` (sic!). There are no visible pointers (where I could do something wrong) there! I don't know how it is possible. It doesn't occur in each place, only in `graphical_engine::draw(figure *f)` and in few places more (I think). Segmentation fault attacks me when I try to do something like: `cached["pos"] = 2`, `cached.begin()->first` etc.. But, step by step:

Firstly I have to note that I'm using in this 'project' C++11. I do not know if that information will be helpful, but...

I'm also using SFML library to open a window and write text in it.

I am creating some graphic application in OpenGL. I got stuck in place where I created a kind of cache. I want to store in the cache an index of vertex attribute from a shader program. I simply don't want to 'charge' it using `glGetAttribLocation` more than once (the first time I call `glVertexAttribPointer` and the second time: use `glEnableVertexAttribArray`), so I've chose 'caching' it in `std::map<std::string, GLuint>`.

In my application I've written a few classes responsible for: application logics, graphics. In graphics class I declared auxiliary types: `shader`, `shader_program`. I am writing it because when I call `s.is_cached("pos")` in, e.g `int main`, there is no Segmentation fault. The problem appears when I try to venture to call `s.is_cached("pos")` in my method `void graphics_engine::draw(figure *f)`. Then the famous Segmentation fault appears and it is not funny.

`bool shader_program::is_cached(const char *name)` implementation looks like:

```
bool shader_program::is_cached(const char *name)
{
  std::string attrname = name;

  // p like 'pair'
  for(auto p: cached)
  {
    if(p.first == attrname) return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Compilator `g++ (...) -std=c++0x` with an option `-g -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` produces code which interacts with my gdb and it returns

```
__gnu_debug::_Safe_sequence_base::_M_attach_single (this=0xb7b805c9, 
    __it=0xbffff478, __constant=false)
    at ../../.././libstdc++-v3/src/debug.cc:274
274       __it->_M_next->_M_prior = __it;
```

If you don't understand any of my code, please, post a comment.

The full code: http://jackweb.ovh.org/OGL.zip

What causes the segmentation fault?

Comment: Haven't read the code, but is there any way the cache could be changed while `is_cached` is iterating over it?

Comment: @Chris Wong: Firstly, thanks for the answer. No -- is_cached doesn't modify `cached` and at each iteration, new `cached.begin()` is created.

Comment: Why dont you use `return cached.find(name) != cached.end()` for `is_cached()`? `std::map` is a sorted-by-key container and it will be faster than simply iterating.

Comment: Can you make a [small self-contained correct example](http://sscce.org/) that distills your code to the *core* of the problem?

Comment: I read part of your program and discovered:

`logical_engine::logical_engine(...) : ...
{
  graphical_engine::shader s(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
  ...
  basic_sp.attach(s);
}`

This will put a dangling reference to a destroyed variable into basic_sp, which will cause segfaults. Now, it's not likely to cause segfaults in `std::map`, which is the kind of dangling variable I was looking for, but you could have made the same kind of mistake around your map. Look for that. If you can't find it, follow awoodland's advice.

Comment: @kukyakya: thanks for your advice; @Jeffrey Yasskin: I corrected basic_sp.attach(s) issue, now I am returning a reference to variable allocated by keyword `new`, but it didn't help :( I am debugging... I partly worked around the problem by passing shader_program &sp to void draw proc (instead of getting it in the proc from logical_engine and it works, but it's overcomplicated - it can be done simplier, but that simplier way causes sigsegv :()

Comment: Solved! The issue was while dereferencing pointer that was not initialized! (constructor of app class).

Comment: @jackweb, please post your answer as an answer so the question can be closed.

Comment: @kukyakya: it's even simpler to just do `return cached.count(name);`